# Protractor: setSize() failing with "WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer"

Tags: protractor

Starting October 18th upon upgrading to Chrome 62 my protractor suite started failing with:

```
WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
```

when I called

```
WebDriver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1480)
```

Full stack trace:

```
Stack Trace:
Running "protractor:default" (protractor) task
[10:48:23] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:48:23] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
protractor startup failure: WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
[10:48:24] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1480)
    at setWindowDimensions (/Users/kyle/projects/c/web/build/config/protractor-conf.js:95:43)
    at onPrepare (/Users/kyle/projects/c/web/build/config/protractor-conf.js:71:12)
    at Function.promise (/Users/kyle/projects/c/web/node_modules/q/q.js:682:9)
    at _fulfilled (/Users/kyle/projects/c/web/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/kyle/projects/c/web/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/kyle/projects/c/web/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/kyle/projects/c/web/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/Users/kyle/projects/c/web/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/kyle/projects/c/web/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
[10:48:24] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Env Info:

```
ChromeDriver: chromedriver=2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061), platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64
Chrome : 62.0.3202.62
Protractor: 5.1.2 (connecting directly to chromedriver)
Node: v6.9.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to chromedriver 2.33 fixed my issue.

To specify a version when running webdriver-manager :

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.33
```